# Where does PDO version attribute come from?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I am getting different version strings returned for PDO database drivers for what I think should be the same. The version is obtained by calling this in PHP:

```
Database::getConnection()->version()
```

Which internally is doing this:

```
$this->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION)
```

So it is getting the PDO driver's `ATTR_SERVER_VERSION`. The driver I'm using is mysql, and it is on Linux.

On one machine, running PHP 5.6, it returns `10.2.26-MariaDB-log`.

On the other machine, running PHP 7.2, it returns `5.5.5-10.2.26-MariaDB`.

Both have MariaDB 10.2.26. I don't know if PHP is the reason they are different. Is there a reason why the version string would be different like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually comes from the database. Digging into the source code, I saw that `ATTR_SERVER_VERSION` actually calls `ZVAL_STRING(return_value, (char *)mysql_get_server_info(H->server));`. A comment on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-get-server-info.php says that it's the same as

```
SELECT VERSION() as mysql_version
```

When I tried it, I saw that they matched.

```
 $pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION);
// '5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'

mysql> select version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
```

The MySQL version command says :

> Returns a string that indicates the MySQL server version. The string uses the utf8 character set. The value might have a suffix in addition to the version number. See the description of the version system variable in Section 5.1.7, “Server System Variables”.

--
[version](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_version)

> The version number for the server. The value might also include a suffix indicating server build or configuration information. -log indicates that one or more of the general log, slow query log, or binary log are enabled. -debug indicates that the server was built with debugging support enabled

MariaDB, being forked from MySQL, [has the same version variable](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#version)

> Description: Server version number. It may also include a suffix with
> configuration or build information. -debug indicates debugging support
> was enabled on the server, and -log indicates at least one of the
> binary log, general log or slow query log are enabled, for example
> 10.0.1-MariaDB-mariadb1precise-log. From MariaDB 10.2.1, this variable can be set at startup in order to fake the server version.
>
> Commandline:  -V, --version[=name] (>= MariaDB 10.2.1), --version (<=
> MariaDB 10.2.0)
>
> Scope: Global
>
> Dynamic: No
>
> Type: string

As for the mismatch between the servers, it's something that MariaDB adds to fix an issue with replication servers, but most clients will strip it out. [src from GitHub issue](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/9062#issuecomment-184742936)

> MySQL replication slave code decides what the master can do (binlog
> format, etc) by looking at the first character of the version as sent
> in the handshake packet. When MariaDB went 10.0, MySQL slaves started
> to think it's version 1, and refused to replicate from it.
>
> As a workaround we've implemented this version prefix. MariaDB sends
> an impossible combination in the handshake packet — the version
> "5.5.5" and "support authentication plugins" in the capability field.
> The MariaDB client library detects that and transparently removes the
> fake version prefix.
>
> Of course if you link with not mariadb-aware client library, the
> prefix will be not removed, and you'll see it in the application.

Comment: Very nice answer! Do you know what the `5.5.5-` I'm seeing in front would be? When I run `SELECT VERSION() as mysql_version`, I don't see that part, but I do in PHP. Could that be the driver version?

Comment: I don't think so, since it doesn't appear that PHP is modifying the string at all. It's a bit of a rabbit hole, though, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Found an answer for that. Apparently it is coming from the DB, but `version()` removes it. It's in there to fix a replication slave issue. https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/9062#issuecomment-184742936

Comment: *Of course if you link with not mariadb-aware client library, the prefix will be not removed, and you'll see it in the application.* Very nice. Consider editing that with the link into your answer, rather than just as a comment.